css variables in darken, lighten function
I need to change the colors dynamically from the button. First I am declare the css variable and then declare the scss varaibe to the css variable. It's perfectlly working. But when I try to put the darken or lighten scss function, it throws the error as it's not color.
I need to know, how to do.
In variable.scss
:root{
  --primary_color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  --secondary_color:#ffffff;
}

/* Only use  #nnn, #nnnnnn, rgb(), rgba(), hsl(), hsla(), color(). Mui not support other farmates */
$primary_color:  var(--primary_color);
$secondary_color: var(--secondary_color);

when I am tring to create new vaiable as
$list_button_hover:hover_color($hover);
@function hover_color($color){
    @if(lightness($color) < 50%){
        @return lighten($color,30%);
    }@else{
        @return darken($color,10%);
    }
}

It throws error as
ERROR in ./src/Components/Sidnavbar/Sidnavbar.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/Components/Sidnavbar/Sidnavbar.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
  ╷
4 │ $list_button_hover:hover_color($hover);
  │                                ^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/Components/Sidnavbar/Sidnavbar.scss 4:32  root stylesheet

webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning

I need to change the color dynamically with
    const root = document.documentElement;
root.style.setProperty("--primary_color", "#fff");


Where is the $hover variable?

+1 would be nice to know how hover_color is being called. I assume returned value is stored in $hover.

$list_button_hover was the variable

@santhosh The error says you use a variable name $hover, which is undefined. Where is it?

Sorry for the confusion, actually it's $primary_color not $hover

Based on this info, my presumption is that you want to compute a hover color dynamically based on the value of a CSS variable that can change at runtime.
Note that you can't rely on Sass functions at runtime. They are run at the time of transpilation to CSS, not while your website is "running".
If you're hoping to change --primary-color using JavaScript dynamically at runtime, you can't use Sass functions to generate ancillary colors.

Then how can I handle the ancillary colours?
Do you have any suggestions for this kind of situation?

If you really don't know the primary color until the site is running, then you'll have to rely on something other than Sass. Look into JavaScript libraries for color generation and creating/updating CSS variables (not Sass variables, since they're compiled at build time) on the fly with JS.
